# VBA Excel just won't quit

Tags: excel, vba

The issue that I'm having is that the document will at times import just fine, and at other times it won't.  From what it looks like, Excel is not always closing.  Can anyone suggest a way to make sure that the instance of Excel that is opened is closed?  Or point me to a good reference for this?  I'm using this VBA in MS Access.  Below is my code:

```
Public Function ImportPayment()
Dim fd As FileDialog
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As String

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fd
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Please select a file."
    .Show
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler:
        ws = fd.SelectedItems(1)
        Workbooks.Open (ws)
        Rows("1:9").Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Cells(Rows.count, "L").End(xlUp).EntireRow.Delete
        Excel.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:= _
        "\\servername\serverfolder\serversubfolder\subfolder\sub\file.txt",
        FileFormat:=xlText _ , CreateBackup:=False
        End With

    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Excel.Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Excel.Application.Quit

DoCmd.TransferText acImport, "Specification", "table",
"\\server\serverfolder\serversubfolder\subfolder\sub\file.txt", False
MsgBox ("Your data was imported successfully.")
ImportPayment = Yep
Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    ImportPayment = Nope
    MsgBox ("The upload was canceled.")

End Function
```

Comment: Since I know that the file is always going to be an Excel file, would it be ideal to create an Excel object before the file picker?  I'm just trying to think some ideas through here.  I've been using VBA for about 4 months now, so I'm still pretty inexperienced in this.

Comment: Yes it is: keep control of your Excel object by instantiating an Excel Application object, and adding workbook objects within this application object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
Sub create_excel_instance()

Dim oExcel As Excel.Application
Dim oBook As Excel.Workbook
Set oExcel = CreateObject("excel.application")

oExcel.Visible = True
set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add

'Close
oBook.close
set oBook = nothing 
oExcel.Quit 

End Sub
```

Note: instead of using `ActiveWorkbook`, you'll notice that this piece of code sets a reference to each object. This is good practice; it will save you many bugs and keep a good overview of your created objects.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Kim!  I've tried adding this in, however I'm getting an error that the MS Access database engine cannot access the file as it is currently in use.  I'm using the file locally, so I'm not sure where this is coming from.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you using the code that I posted? If so, on what line do you get the error?

Comment: Hey Kim, your code worked wonderfully.  Unfortunately, I was having issues with VPN and went in the next day and it worked flawlessly.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is going to seem odd, but for me I always have to put that line twice back to back: Application.Quit  Application.Quit  Doing this closes Excel.